# Windows 8 can't open any modern UI app

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-8-upgrade

I just upgraded my machine with Windows 7 Pro x64, to Windows 8 Pro x64, with the Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant.

Everything went great, but none of the Modern UI Apps open, and they do not show any error messages or warnings, they just close right away I opened them.

I tried to open Skydrive, Windows Store, Photo App,Music App, Bing, Videos , Finances and all the available Modern UI apps on my screen

My screen resolution is 1080p, so it is not a resolution issue, I'm using a Windows account , but i switched to Local account but didn't solved the issue.  I ran Windows Update and updated my nVidia video drivers.

I also tried an app called "Metro App Troubleshooter" without luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solved this issue, the problem was caused by Avast Antivirus, i uninstall it , and everything start to work

thank for the support

Comment: Oh yes avast. Avast 2013 will supposedly fix this

Answer (score 2):

Disabling avast Antivirus!, if you have it installed (or removing it altogether), is in fact a solution to this known issue. Troubleshooted and tested today by me, after my recent upgrade to Windows 8 Professional. Of course, if you are not using avast then look for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do a system refresh and see if it works

But, first open a command prompt with administrator privileges and type this

```
sfc /scannow
```

Get back with the results

Comment: will this delete all my existing applications?

Comment: Apps downloaded from the store will be there. But desktop softwares won't be kept. See my edited answer please.